# How get random number value and attach it to file name

Tags: python, python-3.x

if I have 10 files then I call for random number in range and attach it with equal file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string concatenation to create a path to the file of that number. Like this:

```
path = 'D:/my path/' + str(ran) + '.wav'
wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file(path)
```

Here's more information about [string formatting](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python).

Comment: This is typically regarded as the least preferable string concatenation method.

Answer (score 2):

What I might recommend is leveraging a [format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). You can do something like this:

```
path = "/path/to/my/files/{0}.wav"
random_file = path.format(ran)
```

This will be the albsolute path to the randomly selected file, which can then be passed to `from_wave_file`.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to create a dictionary of your files:

```
dic_files = {1 : 'file1.wav', 2: 'file2.wav' ...}
```

then you can simply call the file using:

```
wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file('D:/my path/'+dic_files[ran])
```

Comment: This is space inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is:

```
wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file('D:/my path/{0}.wav'.format(random.randrange(0,10)))
```